# I lost photos while tethering

Tags: raw, tethering

While shooting with Canon 6D wireless tether connection, I lost raw photos. I shot with my remote, and I think I pressed the remote trigger before the image uploaded. Is there any way to get it back? I have tried a card recovery software already.

Answer (score 1):

In a case similar to yours, I've had successful results on linux with this software:

http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/PhotoRec

It's compatible with many other Operating Systems.